PyMC use JAX to compute sample_posterior_predictive with GPU
I'm able to use my GPU to speed up my PyMC model sampling with m.sampling_jax.sample_numpyro_nuts, and it works well in my Linux environment. However, when sampling the posterior_predictive to extend to my idata, I'm stuck using my cpu, making that the bottleneck of my model.
# Sampling
if gpu_available:
    idata = pm.sampling_jax.sample_numpyro_nuts(draws=draws_def, 
                                                tune=tune_def, 
                                                target_accept=targ_acc_def, 
                                                chain_method='vectorized', 
                                                idata_kwargs={"log_likelihood": True})

else:
    idata = pm.sample(draws=draws_def, tune=tune_def, target_accept=targ_acc_def, idata_kwargs={"log_likelihood": True})


idata.extend(pm.sample_posterior_predictive(idata, var_names=["y_obs"]))


You can pass compile_kwargs=dict(mode="JAX") to sample_posterior_predictive
